# 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + … + n > limit value (the input is a limit value)

Tags: java

How do I program in Java to get the smallest positive integer n that satisfies the criteria:
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + … + n > limit value (the input is a limit value)

Example:
The input: 6. Then n is 4 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 > limit value, 10 > 6)
The input: 7. Then n is 4 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 > limit value, 10 > 7)
How?

I've tried it using a WHILE..END-WHILE looping.

```
class LimitValue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, sum, limit_value;
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter limit value: ");
        limit_value = scan.nextInt();
        
        n = 0;
        sum = 0;
        while (sum < limit_value) {
            sum = sum + n;
            n++;
        }
        
        System.out.println("n = " + n);
    }
}
```

But there are some discrepancies in the output:

```
Limit value: 1
n = 2 // (right, 1 + 2 > 1)

Limit value: 2
n = 3 // (wrong, n should be 2 so therefore 1 + 2 > 2)

Limit value: 3
n = 3 // (right, 1 + 2 + 3 > 3)

Limit value: 4
n = 4 // (wrong, n should be 3 so therefore 1 + 2 + 3 > 4)

Limit value: 5
n = 4 // (wrong, n should be 3 so therefore 1 + 2 + 3 > 4)

Limit value: 6
n = 4 // (right, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 > 6)

Limit value: 7
n = 5 // (wrong, n should be 4 so therefore 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 > 7)

Limit value: 8
n = 5 // (wrong, n should be 4 so therefore 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 > 7)

Limit value: 9
n = 5 // (wrong, n should be 4 so therefore 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 > 7)

Limit value: 10
n = 5 // (right, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 > 10)
```

Comment: Make a loop that computes sum and break when the limit is exceeded. Then calculate n from the last available index.

Comment: @qrsngky You don't even need a loop for this because there are already the formula for arithmetic series

Comment: @phuclv in that case one needs to solve a quadratic inequality

Comment: Why is this closed?  This seems like a perfectly reasonable, well focused question.  OP has stated the question clearly, and even provided a couple of examples.  This question requires a bit of mathematical knowledge and a bit of Java knowledge.  It doesn't require more focus.

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger? To see when the algorithm deviates from your expectations?

Comment: @qrsngky but the equation has only 1 positive root and is trivial to solve. Moreover it's O(1) instead of O(n)

Comment: @phuclv I don't think the OP is considering super large N, though (But that's just my guess). Considering small N, a `sqrt` call could be comparatively expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching these 2 statements:

```
sum = sum + n;
n++;
```

So it becomes

```
n++;
sum = sum + n;
```

Because right now you first add `n` to `sum` (which is 0 in the first loop) and then increase `n` but it should be the other way I believe

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it

```
        n = 0;
        sum = 0;
        while (sum <= limit_value) {
            n++;
            sum = sum + n;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
final var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
final var a = scanner.nextInt();
final var n = (int) (.5 * (Math.sqrt(8 * a + 1) + 1));
System.out.println(n);
```